# iOS Line SDK Login failed : Error User Cancelled or Interrupted the login process

Tags: ios, swift

I downloaded line-sdk-ios-swift-master from GitHUB . And then replace keys with my Line account key  , replace project identifier to com.myproject.yeah , i can successfully login and retrieve AuthID.

But problem occur when i try to replicate the same thing on my project.

I copied the exactly same codes from  line-sdk-ios-swift-master (Utils , LoginViewController , etc ) And setup the .plist .

I can pass the login , the sdk asked me for permission . (cancel allow) , it redirect me to  "MYAPPNAME" and  "openthisapp?" (cancel ok )

After i clicked  (ok) and "open in "myapp""

It redirect me back to the App with , But the login is Failed with Error "User canceled or interrupted the login process"

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the app opening in your `AppDelegate`:

```swift
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return LoginManager.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

If not, LINE SDK will think your user switched back to your app without any result and fail your login.

For more, you can check the documentation page [here](https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/ios-sdk/swift/integrate-line-login/). It is described in step 3.